# Android MediaControler does not work with video from url

Tags: android, seekbar, mediacontroller

I have video player, video is from url. It works- I can start and stop playing video. I would like to have a possibility to move progres in MediaController. I have set the MediaController, but it doesn't work. When I use a video from file i can  seek/move the  video progress, but with the video from url it doesn't work.
There is my code:

```
videoFrame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.videoField);
mediaController = new MediaController(VideoPage.this);
videoPlayer = new VideoView(context);
videoFrame.addView(videoPlayer);
videoPlayer.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(url));
mediaController.setMediaPlayer(videoPlayer);
videoPlayer.setMediaController(mediaController);
videoPlayer.requestFocus();
videoPlayer.start();
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to check if you can seek forward:

```
if(videoPlayer.canSeekForward()){
   ...
}
```

and this is just possible, when you get a duration for the videostream, but some streams don't have a duration, for example if you stream tv content or a live stream.

```
int duration = videoPlayer.getDuration()
```